# Responsive Page - Overflow Issue

Tags: css, responsive-design, overflow, media-queries

I'm trying to determine what could be causing the horizontal scroll bar to appear on [this page](http://www.tuilifestyle.com/realtor-referral-program/). It only appears when I re-size the page to inherit the following media query...

```
@media (max-width: 979px) and (min-width: 768px)
```

Oddly enough, it happens when I toggle from Portrait to Landscape and back on the iPad or if I resize my browser back and forth. When I load the page the first time at this size on the iPad or the computer, it does not have a horizontal scroll bar.

Using process of elimination, I'm able to determine that it's something in the contact form at the bottom but I can't for the life of me determine what DIV it is so that I can fix it. I was even going to use overflow-x: hidden, but that doesn't fix the issue when I toggle back and forth on the iPad between orientations.

This is such a small issue and I'm hoping that I'm missing something obvious.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: We could better help if we could see your code. Do you have a page up somewhere we could see?

Comment: Hey there, Chris!

Thank you. I've linked to the page in the first sentence at the end.

Comment: It happens on my browser (Firefox/Ubuntu) because the banner is not successfully dropping to the next line, making the page width to large for the window.

Comment: Hey there! Do you mean the slider? If so, I'll take a look right now at that. Oddly enough I had removed it but it was still happening on that page.

Comment: I got the smae the slider move to the right of the page from 768 - 782 then dropped in underneath after and the scroller disappeared

Comment: Hey there guys! I just deleted the slider from the page and notice it's still happening. Is it possible that you guys could look into it further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just checked your page. Just check whether you've given more width ( summing: box-width+border_margin ) value of any child element form its parent element. And use overflow: hidden if you are sure about what i said. Hope you get it.